# Controller that supports multiple LCDs, ideally up to 5

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, .net-micro-framework

Are there any controllers that support multiple LCDs? Ideally I'd like to connect up to 5 LCDs to a single controller. The sort of LCDs I'm mainly interested in are smallish units around 320 x 240 such as this [one](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/276).

It would be even better if the controller was compatible with the .net Micro Framework but that's not essential.

Comment: Use LCDs that are communicated via serial protocols, like SPI or I2C. Of course, they will not be as fast as doing parallel. If you want speed, you can do some kind of muxing the parallel signal to different LCDs, but that is a lot of trace! A serial LCD example [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MK-GT380N/681-1015-ND/1843452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say controller, you mean a microcontroller, the confusion only arises because LCDs themselves have controllers.

The answer is yes, the [STM32F103RE](http://www.st.com/internet/mcu/product/164485.jsp) would work for what you want to do. It's compatible with the .net micro framework and it has plenty of options to run serial displays on, be it SPI, I2C, or asynchronous serial. Perhaps a display like [this one](http://www.lcd-module.de/eng/pdf/grafik/edip240-7e.pdf).

Whichever display you go with, try to find one with onboard memory, you'll save yourself some headaches that way.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments using Serial interfaced LCD's is a good solution. Basically they expose API calls that allow you load images from SD card, manipualte them, overlay other images, superimpose shapes and text. You just need to write your own classes in .net micro todo what you need it to do.

I have bought a [serial LCD from uLCD](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/products.php?cat=26) - They are really great - and you can flash between firmware to give you complete control.

The back with the Serial port on the bottom left.

[image]

The LCD.

[image]

Comment: "Serial interfaced LCD's is a good solution. Basically they expose API calls that allow you load images from SD card" At first I thought there was a subject pronoun confusion here, but I see we're not talking about the same serial LCDs. A serial LCD is and LCD that communicates in a serial fashion, at least in my definition. Does the µLCD board support multiple LCDs or at some sort of external controller?

Comment: @Samuel - By serial in this context, he means traditional RS-232 style signaling. Basically, these LCDs have a very involved controller that can do complex graphical operations with simple commands. They're not a pixel-addressed-only LCD at all.

Comment: @FakeName My mistake was that I thought this answer was offering a complete package, not just a suggestion for an LCD alone. My, apologies. These suggested LCDs combined with a proper microcontroller would indeed be a good solution.

Comment: @Samuel Sorry I never realised there were serial pixel controlled LCD's - Yes this is a complete package and the uLCD is a very mature one- There are others on ebay / seeed too. To use more screen you just it to another serial (TTL) port or bitbanged IO pins, or some sort of TTL expander. I have not seen screens that can be daisy chained. (OH I forgot to say you can flash the LCD screen package with you own code and it also has IO pins- to control other LCD's? - but it uses their own libraries)

Comment: @ppumkin - There aren't *RS232* pixel-addressed displays, as far as I know. However, there SPI (which is also technically *serial*, just not asynchronous) pixel-addressed displays. You should probably clarify that by serial, you mean *asynchronous* serial.

Answer (score 1):

SPI-based LCDs can be quite fast, and it is relatively easy to interface an arbitrary number of them to one microcontroller with a small number of I/O pins and a small amount of extra circuitry.  For example, if you want to connect up to seven such LCDs using three I/O pins and one external 74HC164, you could wire the clock and data inputs of all the LCDs to the clock and data outputs of the processor's SPI port, wire the data input of the 74HC164 to the SPI data wire, and the clock input of the '164 to an extra I/O pin on the processor.  Wire seven of the '164 outputs to the chip-selects on the displays, and the eighth to the register-select input of the displays (if they have one).  To output data to some or all the displays, bit-bang the desired bit pattern to the '164, and then use the SPI port to blast data to the display.